# Custom VF Email Template is not recognizing my custom visualforce component as global

Tags: email, salesforce, visualforce, custom-component, email-templates

Hi All and thank you for taking the time to look at my question!

I created a custom vf component to query some information and send an email to a lead. Here is the component tag:

```
   <apex:component access="global"  controller="My_Component_Name">
```

Please note the attribute access="global".

In my VF Email Template I include the component as follows:

```
<c:My_Component_Name cust_field="{!relatedTo.Custom_Field__c}">
</c:My_Component_Name>
```

However, when I try to include this component in a VF Email Template, I get the following error:

```
Error: <messaging:emailTemplate> can only contain components with an access
 level of global. <c:my_component_name> is not valid.
```

I tried waiting, in case there was a time lag, I tried deleting the content and resaving, I even tried cloning the component and including the cloned version. Nothing helps.

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do?

*I changed the names of the components and fields, so please don't comment on possible typos in the names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is VERY embarrassing, but just in case someone else makes this mistake I will admit it:

I was working in two different orgs at the same time :( My component with access="global" was in sandbox and the VF template was in Prod.